# How do I find the sum of the last row of data?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a row of numbers added every day automatically. I want a function to find out the sum of the last row of numbers, as that last row contains the most up-to-date information.

Here is an example spreadsheet of what I mean:

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:E,MATCH(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))))
```

Match to find the last row and sum up.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Works when new rows of data are added, even if they are incomplete :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A1);"";SUM(A1:E1)))
```

insert it in first row in the cell where you want to have SUM and then autocomplete it with dragging it down in the column till the end of the sheet

Comment: I have the data in one sheet and a summary of the data in another sheet, so I will need only the sum of the last row's values in my Summary data sheet. I don't want to go into the sheet with all the data and scroll down to the last row to find the sum.